# How to dismiss the end of the url parameters with regex?

Tags: regex, url, url-parameters

I have a script that is supposed to trigger when a certain page path is open.

The issue: the page path contains multiple parameters including the parameter "**returnUrl**", returning the previous page visited.

Here is the url I want to check :

```
/cxsSearchApply?positionId=a0w0X000004IceYQAS&lang=en&returnUrl=https://example.com/cxsrec__cxsSearchDetail?id=a0w0X000004IceYQAS&lang=en&returnUrl=https://example.com/cxsrec__cxsSearch&lang=en
```

I initially used this regex code to get triggered on this page :

```
(cxsSearchApply.*)
```

But I have others regex codes like:

```
(cxsSearchSearchDetail.*)
```

And they also trigger because of the page path included in the url...

What reggex I should use to match the first part of the url but nothing after "**returnUrl**" ?

Comment: So what exactly is the expected result?

Comment: You could use a regex like `^[^?#]*cxsSearchApply` That will disallow "?" and "#" before "cxsSearchApply". [visualisation](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B%5E%3F%23%5D*cxsSearchApply%2F)

Comment: Please be clear and show your tries and your current output vs expected output. There are two `returnUrl` params in your URL. Please add expected output clearly. Also always try and put a language in regex post tags, as each regex engine has their own limitations and capabilities.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear in the the question... I wanted everything before the first "returnUrl".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to match `cxsSearchApply` on the text *before* `&returnUrl`. You could use a lookahead:

```
(cxsSearchApply.*)(?=returnUrl=)
```

However, what you really want is to match everything before the *first* `&returnUrl`. So you need a non-greedy operator:

```
(cxsSearchApply.*?)(?=returnUrl=)
```

Likewise, for your other search, it should no longer match because it is also only looking at the first part:

```
(cxsSearchSearchDetail.*?)(?=returnUrl=)
```

I believe that will get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing after "**returnUrl**"

If this is literally what you want, you can simply do `(.*)(&returnUrl=.*)` and take the first capture group as your result.

Comment: it works, but I do not want to capture the second group.

Comment: It works fine... but I wanted to exclude the second group after this returnUrl